# Laravel change route of RESTful controller

Tags: rest, routes, laravel

I've decided to split up my users logic into a controller to clean up my routes file, going down the RESTful route i've got something like:

```
UsersController {
    getLogin() {
    }
    postLogin() {
    }
}
```

Only now i'm stick with /users/login and /users/register etc..

I need to change them to /login and /register, i've researched and not found a definitive answer, i tried the named route method:

```
Route::get('users/login', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'UsersController@getLogin'));
```

But it says not found, after a bit of T&E i found a working route:

```
Route::get('login', 'UsersController@getLogin');
```

Only now i'm explicitly defining every method.. does this defeat the object of RESTful when i'm defining the verb twice?

It would be awesome if Laravel could work out what method is being requested then i could do something like the following and be done with:

```
Route::any('login', 'UsersController@Login');
```

As far as i know, this can't be done... so is it pointless trying to work RESTful in this situation and should just use named routing for all my methods?

Answer (score 1):

The restful controllers are only useful for cases where there are no exceptions in the routing to it.

The limitation for these restful controllers is that the buildup is always the same:
{ControllerAlias}/{Method}/{Parameter}

You would define these by using `Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');`

What you can do, is use named routings for the exceptions, but use the restful controllers for everything else.

Another option is to create an "index" controller, which contains the getLogin / postLogin and getRegister / postRegister methods.

The route would be something like: `Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');`

Personally I type out all possible routes, I do this so I know exactly what my visitors will be able to see, which is not only a good thing for security (White listing is always a good start for security), it also helps me to think better about what a page should do, and what functions it should, or maybe shouldn't have.
Which eventually provide better structured code. But that's more my personal view of routing.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use function names as getLogin and postLogin you have a couple of options.
First one is to call controller in your routes

```
Route::controller('auth', 'AuthController');//or whatever is the name of your controller
```

and if you want to add additional routes to REST-full resource you need to specify them **BEFORE** the resource call

```
Route::get('login','AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('login','AuthController@postLogin');
Route::resource('login', 'AuthController');
```